# To test the performance of Database by simulating in Java

Tags: java, database, multithreading, testing

The requirement is to build a tool in Java which takes a set of queries as input, and prints the response time of the queries as the output.

This is to test the performance of the DataBase, when a large number of queries hit the DB (around 1000) at around the same time and to get the details of how much each query might take under this scenario.

This thing has to be simulated in Java. How do I go about it. I am thinking Threads. Is it the right way(separate threads for each query). If not, what should I do?

Comment: Is it homework? or you actually want to analyze the performance of your queries?

Comment: You question is entirely unclear.  Are you trying to amass statistics about queries that have run and apply them?  Are you building a testing system that runs the queries?  Are you trying to emulate the database to figure out run times?  Are you analyzing the execution plans of proposed queries?  On the surface, what you are trying to do is probably harder than building the database engine itself.

Comment: Its a tool which I am building for the performance team, which they'l be using to analyse the performance of the queries. They want the details of the response time if a large number of queries are to hit the DB at the same time. For obtaining these details, I will have to build a tool.

Comment: @Jhurtado I just need to get the response time for each queries. Analyzing will be done by others

Answer (score 3):

You can acomplish this by using [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html).it is open source software, a 100% pure Java application designed to load test functional behavior and measure performance.

Comment: can it take multiple queries and tell us how much time they might take if they are to execute simultaneously? Since I was given this task by the performance team, I wonder why they don't know about such a tool. I guess you are expected to know this if you are into performance testing?

Comment: Yes, it can... you can add multiple jdbc requests and you can add Listeners to analyze individual response times. Also, this is a very common tool for performance testers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix SQL statements to improve the performance you can do *without* threads.

If you really want to know how Database behaves in real-time you should go for threads.